# Units of JMol XYZ

Tags: java, chemistry

XYZ files specify atoms and their cartesian coordinates.

Example XYZ file:

```
[Number of atoms]
Comment
[Chemical symbol] [X] [Y] [Z]
```

I was wondering what the units used were in [JMol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) (i.e., Angstroms or Bohr radii)

Comment: Did you try a search on Google?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful You don't need units for parsing the file/rendering/etc., but if you want to graph it with any scale, you need units.

Comment: not related to programming at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What are the units used in JMol (Angstroms or Bohr radii)?

> The units are generally in **ångströms**

---

#### XYZ file format

> The XYZ file format is a chemical file format. There is no formal standard and several variations exist, but a typical XYZ format specifies the molecule geometry by giving the number of atoms with Cartesian coordinates that will be read on the first line, a comment on the second, and the lines of atomic coordinates in the following lines.
>
> The file format is used in computational chemistry programs for importing and exporting geometries.
>
> The units are generally in **ångströms**.

Source [XYZ file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format)